# doc.size(), doc.keySet() in painless gives unsupported_operation_exception: null

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to transform a set of documents, and i have a bunch of `x.y.a`, `x.y.b`, `x.y.c` ... etc properties i would like to filter and remap to `props.a`, `props.b`

It seems like a `scripted_metric` aggregation is the only way to achieve this. The idea is i could do something a bit like:

```
Map m = new HashMap()
for (k in doc.keySet()) {
  if (k.startsWith('x.y.'){
    m[k] = doc[k];
  }
}
```

(loosely)

If i use the example here https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/script-apis/exec-script/#script-contexts

I create an index mapping

```
PUT /testindex1
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "grad": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "gpa": {
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use painless execute

```
POST /_scripts/painless/_execute
{
  "script": {
    "source": "def x = doc.size(); return true;",
    "params": {
      "min_honors_gpa": 3.5
    }
  },
  "context": "filter",
  "context_setup": {
    "index": "testindex1",
    "document": {
      "grad": true,
      "gpa": 3.79
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "unsupported_operation_exception",
        "reason": "unsupported_operation_exception: null"
      }
    ],
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "org.opensearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.size(LeafDocLookup.java:123)",
      "x = doc.size(); ",
      "       ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "def x = doc.size(); return true;",
    "lang": "painless",
    "position": {
      "offset": 11,
      "start": 4,
      "end": 20
    },
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "unsupported_operation_exception",
      "reason": "unsupported_operation_exception: null"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

It seems that trying to access anything other than an explicit key in `doc`, i.e. `doc['gpa'].value` gives the `unsupported_operation_exeception`

I am kinda new to opensearch and I am just wondering
a) why i cant access anything in `doc`
b) how i might be able to do that remapping/capturing a subset of a documents attributes for a transform without explicitly listing them all